# How to see the full command used to run a container in a Kubernetes pod?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-container

In Docker we can see the full command used to run a container using

```
docker ps --no-trunc
```

In case of containers inside pods in a Kubernetes cluster, how to find this same info?

I also tried to describe a pod using `kubectl describe pods test-77f45b7bd7-hqvqh -n somenp` but it doesn't show that information:

```
Containers:
  data-exploration:
    Container ID:   docker://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    Image:          docker_uri
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://docker_uri
    Port:           3002/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Fri, 22 Dec 2023 10:37:25 +0000
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:     1
      memory:  5Gi
    Requests:
      cpu:     500m
      memory:  1Gi
    Environment:
```

Comment: I'm also interested in finding out the answer to this question, but there's currently 1 close vote to this question due to [docker](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/docker/info) and [kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/kubernetes/info) questions being borderline off-topic. If you want, this can also be asked over at [DevOps StackExchange](https://devops.stackexchange.com/) where this question is more on-topic and where it can get another chance at an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kubectl only output the `command` (ENTRYPOINT) and `args` (CMD) that you have defined in the container manifest section (if any). kubectl does not output the default ENTRYPOINT/CMD set in the image like what `docker ps --no-trunc` does.